# Bit shift for 32 and 64 unsigned integers

Tags: c++

I have a question with this snippet of code:

```
uint32_t c = 1 << 31;
uint64_t d = 1 << 31;
cout << "c: " << std::bitset<64>(c) << endl;
cout << "d: " << std::bitset<64>(d) << endl;
cout << (c == d ? "equal" : "not equal") << endl;
```

The result is:

```
c: 0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000
d: 1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
not equal
```

Yes, I know that the solution for 'd' is to use '1ULL'. But I cannot understand why this happens when the shift is of 31 bits. I read somewhere that it is safe to shift size-1 bits, so if I write the instruction without the 'UUL' and the literal '1' is 32 bits long then it should be safe to shift it 31 bits, right? 
What am I missing here?

Regards

YotKay

Comment: Right. Thank you!

Comment: "Yes, I know that the solution for 'd' is to use '1ULL'." you know wrong, 1U is enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the expression that you shift left, namely, the constant `1`, is treated as a signed integer. That is why the compiler performs sign extension on it *before* assigning the result to `d`, causing the result that you see.

Adding suffix `U` to `1` will fix the problem ([demo](http://ideone.com/xWeVJm)).

```
uint64_t d = 1U << 31;
```

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot!